# Decrease precision Sympy Equality Class

Tags: precision, sympy

I am performing some symbolic calculations using Sympy, and the calculations are just too computationally expensive. I was hoping to minimize the number of bytes used per calculation, and thus increase processing speed. I am solving two polynomial equations for two unknowns, but whenever i create the Equalities using the Sympy equality class it introduces precision that did not exist in the variables supplied. It adds extra numbers to the ends to create the 15 point precision standard of sympy. I was hoping there might be a way to keep this class from doing this, or just limit the overall precision of sympy for this problem, as this amount of precision is not necessary for my calculations. I have read through all the documentation i can find on the class, and on precision handling in sympy with no luck. 
My code looks like this.

c0=np.float16((math.cos(A)**2)/(a**2)+(math.sin(A)**2)/(b**2))

c1=np.float16((math.cos(A)**2)/(b**2)+(math.sin(A)**2)/(a**2))

c2=np.float16((math.sin(2*A))/(a**2)-(math.sin(2*A))/(b**2))

c3=np.float16((k*math.sin(2*A))/(b**2)-(2*h*(math.cos(A))**2)/(a**2)-(k*(math.sin(2*A)))/(a**2)-(2*h*(math.sin(A))**2)/(b**2))

c4=np.float16((h*math.sin(2*A))/(b**2)-(2*k*(math.cos(A))**2)/(b**2)-(h*(math.sin(2*A)))/(a**2)-(2*k*(math.sin(A))**2)/(a**2))

c5=np.float16((h**2*(math.cos(A))**2)/(a**2)+(k*h*(math.sin(2*A)))/(a**2)+(k**2*(math.sin(A))**2)/(a**2)+(h**2*(math.sin(A))**2)/(b**2)+(k**2*(math.cos(A))**2)/(b**2)-(k*h*(math.sin(2*A)))/(b**2)-1)

x=sym.Symbol('x', real=True)

y=sym.Symbol('y', real=True)

e=sym.Eq(c0*x**2+c1*y**2+c2*x*y+c3*x+c4*y+c5)

Each value of c5 originally calculates to double precision float as normal with python, and since i don't require that precision i just recast it as float16. So the values look like

c0=1.547

c1=15.43

c2=1.55

c3=5.687

c4=7.345

c5=6.433

However when cast into the equality e. The equation becomes

e=1.5470203040506025*x**2 + 15.43000345000245*y**2....etc

with the standard sympy 15 point precision on every coefficient, even though those numbers are not representative of the data. 
I'm hoping that lowering this precision i might decrease my run time. I have a lot of these polynomials to solve for. I've already tried using sympy's float class, and eval function, and many other things. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that changing the precision will improve the runtime. It might be better to try and use sympy to get a general formula and then evaluate that numerically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the number of significant figures to Float as the second argument:

```
.>> from sympy import Float, Eq
>>> c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 = [Float(i,4) for i in (c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)]
>>> Eq(c0*x**2+c1*y**2+c2*x*y+c3*x+c4*y+c5,0)
Eq(1.547*x**2 + 1.55*x*y + 5.687*x + 15.43*y**2 + 7.345*y + 6.433, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what i was looking for. However, Oscar was correct, and it didn't help my processing time.